# How to delete specific strings from a file?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a data file (unstructured, messy file) from which I have to scrub specific list of strings (delete strings).

Here is what I am doing but with no result:

```
infile = r"messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = r"cleaned_file.txt"

delete_list = ["firstname1 lastname1","firstname2 lastname2"....,"firstnamen lastnamen"]
fin=open(infile,"")
fout = open(outfile,"w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

When I execute the file, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error or is it just not outputting a file but the script appears to execute?

Comment: No I am not getting any error..The file appears to execute. Does the .py file generate a log file which I can look at. I dont see anything in the directory.

Comment: After execution, does cleaned_file.txt exist?

Comment: no I dont see cleaned_file.txt..

Comment: What platform are you running on? Does the user executing the program have write permission in the directory the program is running in?

Comment: Add a print statement after your fout = and file_data lines. Print anything but just verify your program is executing that far. The other thought I had was use a fully qualified path for your in and out file. That way there is not an opportunity for the file to be written to an unexpected location.

Comment: Yes i have write permissions!

Comment: Appologies. I am trying to delete strings. Not sure how to make it work.

Comment: How are you executing it? What are you typing at the command line to run it?

Comment: I am double clicking the .py file. It seems to invoke the python application which disappears after a couple of seconds. I dont get any error thought..

Comment: -1: The indentation is so wrong, it's impossible to judge what's going on.

Comment: Run it from a command prompt so that you can see anything that it outputs immediately before closing.

Comment: You are not executing the listed code if you received an error message that 'word' is not defined.

Comment: The `NameError: name 'word' is not defined` only occurs when you have typing error. may be your definition line have an incorrect spell same: `for worLd in delete_list:`? or an case-sensitive problem like `for WORD in delete_list:` ?

Answer (score 20):

The [`readlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines) method returns a list of *lines*, not words, so your code would only work where one of your words is on a line by itself.

Since [files are iterators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.next) over lines this can be done much easier:

```
infile = "messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = "cleaned_file.txt"

delete_list = ["word_1", "word_2", "word_n"]
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Ross..I tried your code, except I am not seeing an optput file. Not sure why it is not getting created.

Comment: Appologies, I am trying to delete strings..not sure how to make code work.

Comment: Then you need to ask a specific question, not just say it's not working.  I get an output file every time with the code above.

Comment: ok. I made modification based on the suggestions. I am see a blank output file now. When I run the script, it gives me error at fout.write(line). ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Avoid long comment threads.  Update your question with a *complete traceback*.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the string within the same file, I used this code

```
f = open('./test.txt','r')
a = ['word1','word2','word3']
lst = []
for line in f:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word,'')
    lst.append(line)
f.close()
f = open('./test.txt','w')
for line in lst:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "I am double clicking the .py file. It seems to invoke the python application which disappears after a couple of seconds. I dont get any error thought" I believe your issue is the script is not finding the input file. That is also why you are not getting any output. When you double click on it... I actually can't recall where the interpreter is going to look but I think it's where the python.exe is installed.

Use a fully qualified path like so.

```
# Depends on your OS
infile = r"C:\tmp\messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = r"C:\tmp\cleaned_file.txt"

infile = r"/etc/tmp/messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = r"/etc/tmp/cleaned_file.txt"
```

Also, for your sanity, run it from the command-line instead of double clicking. It'll be much easier to catch errors/output.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion. I see a cleaned_file.txt which is empty..When I run the script in command prompt I get an error at fout.write(line). It says the ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Ask a new question with the updated code and updated information about how you're running it.

Answer (score 1):

To the OP, 
Ross Patterson's method above works perfectly for me, i.e.

```
infile = "messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = "cleaned_file.txt"

delete_list = ["word_1", "word_2", "word_n"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Example:

I have a file named messy_data_file.txt that includes the following words (animals), not necessarily on the same line. Like this:

```
Goat
Elephant
Horse Donkey Giraffe
Lizard
Bird
Fish
```

When I modify the code to read (actually just adding the words to delete to the "delete_list" line):

```
infile = "messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = "cleaned_file.txt"

delete_list = ["Donkey", "Goat", "Fish"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
       line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

The resulting "cleaned_file.txt" looks like this:

```
Elephant
Horse  Giraffe
Lizard
Bird
```

There is a blank line where "Goat" used to be (where, oddly, removing "Donkey" did not) but for my purposes, this works fine.

I also add **input("Press Enter to exit...")** the the very end of the code to keep the command line window from opening and slamming shut on me when I'm double-clicking the remove_text.py file to run it, but take note that you'll catch no errors this way.

To do that I run it from the command line (where C:\Just_Testing is the directory where all my files are, i.e. remove_text.py and messy_text.txt)
like this:

```
C:\Just_Testing\>py remove_text.py
```

or

```
C:\Just_Testing>python remove_text.py
```

works exactly the same.

Of course, like when writing HTML, I guess it never hurts to use a fully qualified path when running py or python from somewhere other than the directory you happen to be sitting in, such as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\>python C:\Users\Me\Desktop\remove_text.py
```

Of course in the code it would be:

```
infile = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\messy_data_file.txt"
outfile = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\cleaned_file.txt"
```

Be careful to use the same fully qualified path to place your newly created cleaned_file.txt in or it will be created wherever you may be and that could cause confusion when looking for it.

Personally, I have the PATH in my Environment Variables set to point to all my Python installs i.e. C:\Python3.5.3, C:\Python2.7.13, etc. so I can run py or python from anywhere.

Anyway, I hope making fine-tuning adjustments to this code from Mr. Patterson can get you exactly what you need. :)

.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add encoding='utf-8' in your fin and fout variables.
***Here is the modified one you may want to use:***

```
fin=open(infile,"", encoding='utf-8')
fout = open(outfile,"w+", encoding='utf-8')
```

***This(adding utf-8) mostly occurs on the OS Windows. Also for reading, writing, and appending the file, this usually isn't a problem but for advanced things to do a file like replacing text in there, etc then you should do this.***

***Hope this helps you.***

Answer (score 0):

The code below just gets the old data and checks if the string doesnt contain the string you doesnt want then continues. *(this also works if you want to remove empty lines)*

```py
str = []
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        str.append(i)
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in str:
        if i != "The string you want to remove":
           f.write(i)
```