# How can i delete words from a txt document in python

Tags: python, file, text, delete-file, delete-row

I want to know how I can delete a word inputted by the user i.e "ant" from a text file. Each word in the text file is already separated into different lines:

```
ant
Cat
Elephant
...
```

This is what I have:

```
def words2delete():
   with open('animals_file.txt') as file:
       delete_word= input('enter an animal to delete from file')
```

Comment: Read all lines and, for each line, remove the input word and rewrite it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Deleting specific strings from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356043/python-deleting-specific-strings-from-file)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way

```
delete_word = input('enter an animal to delete from file') # use raw_input on python 2
with open('words.txt') as fin, open('words_cleaned.txt', 'wt') as fout:
    list(fout.write(line) for line in fin if line.rstrip() != delete_word)
```

Comment: This solution works great. Also, I am using `python2.7` and needed to add `raw_` to `input` function, in case this helps out OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
with open('animals_file.txt', '') as fin:
   with open('cleaned_file.txt', 'w+') as fout:
       delete_word= input('enter an animal to delete from file')

       for line in fin:
           if line != delete_word:
               fout.write(line+'\n')
```

If you need to change on the same file, the best option is to usually rename your file into something like `animals_file.txt.old` (avoids losing information in crashes) and writing the new file. If everything finishes successfully, you can delete the `.old`

Comment: what about the `\n` at the end of each line in the file?

Comment: Voilá! Just add '\n' to the line being written

Comment: the comparison isn't working since `\n` is part of the line read form the file

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK python reads each line without the `\n`. Anyway, use the `.rstrip()` method on `line`

Comment: the best thing to do is to try it out for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple like this

```
file_read = open('animals_file.txt', 'r')
animals = file_read.readlines()
delete_animal = input('delete animal: ')
animals.remove(delete_animal)
file_write = open('animals_file.txt', 'w')
for animal in animals:
    file_write.write(animal)
file_write.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting the text file into a list first. Each line in the file will be an element in the list. It will remove the specified word from all the locations in the text file

```
toremove='ant'
word=toremove+'\n' #add new line format with the word to be removed
infile= open('test.txt','r')
lines= infile.readlines() #converting all lines to listelements
infile.close()
# make new list, consisting of the words except the one to be removed
newlist=[i for i in lines if i!=word]  #list comprehension 
outfile= open('test.txt','w')
outfile.write("".join(newlist))
outfile.close
```

Another way to implement the same technique:

```
word='ant'
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
    newlist= [i for i in infile.read().split() if i!=word]
with open('test.txt','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(newlist))
```