# Separate a variable into 3 variables, and remove parts text after

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a variable, `first_line` which is in the format of `1888,60,-32`, and I want to separate this, for example, to equal `x = 1888` `y = 60` and `z = -32`, but they might be different lengths, eg, another one is `768,60,-13776`.

I have [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356043/python-deleting-specific-strings-from-file) and it didn't allow me to split up the text into variables.

`write.py`

```
# open current file and read first line
with open(currentfile) as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    first_line = first_line.rstrip()
print(currentfile)
print(first_line)

# define fullnamejson as END + first_line + .json
fullnamejson = "END_" + first_line + ".json"

# define fullname as END + first_line
fullname = "END_" + first_line

os.rename(currentfile, fullnamejson)
print(fullnamejson)

# define x y and z
x = "some value x"
y = "some value y"
z = "some value z"

# define formatted as what will be written to the file
formatted = "{\n  \"id\": \"" + fullname + "\",\n  \"name\": \"END\",\n  \"icon\": \"waypoint-normal.png\",\n  \"x\": " + x + ",\n  \"y\": " + y + ",\n  \"z\": " + z + ",\n}"
print(formatted)

# write to file
with open(fullnamejson, "w") as text_file:
    ##print(f(fullnamejson), file=text_file)
    print(f'{formatted}', file=text_file)
```

`zzz_split_1.txt` (input)

```
1888,60,-32
```

`fullnamejson` (output)

```
{
  "id": "END_1888,60,-32",
  "name": "END",
  "icon": "waypoint-normal.png",
  "x": some value x,
  "y": some value y,
  "z": some value z,
}
```

Comment: Do you need anything more complicated than `x, y, z = first_line.split(',', 3)`?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I need x y and z as separate values. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. I assume that would split it and remove, hopefully?  And if you have `x, y, z =` as that you can use them separately? I'm assuming since I'm kind of new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
coords = first_line.split(",")
x, y, z = int(coords[0]), int(coords[1]), int(coords[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can split strings using function split.
2. You can assign result of expression that is a collection to more than one variable.

All written above looks like that in code:

```
x, y, z =your_string.split(',')
```

Just change quotation marks.(writing from iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You were close, all you needed was to use `split` to divide the content!

```
f=open("a.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents =f.read()
    f.close()
arr = contents.split(",")
fullnamejson = "END_" + contents + ".json"
print(fullnamejson)
fullname = "END_" + contents
formatted = "{\n  \"id\": \"" + fullname + "\",\n  \"name\": \"END\",\n  \"icon\": \"waypoint-normal.png\",\n  \"x\": " + contents[0] + ",\n  \"y\": " + contents[1] + ",\n  \"z\": " + contents[2] + ",\n}"
print(formatted)

with open(fullnamejson, "w") as text_file:
    print(f'{formatted}', file=text_file)
```