# Python - Remove string from TXT file

Tags: python, data-structures

I tried to solve it in many different ways but I never get it to work properly.
My problem is that I have a list of users that it is a TXT file and I want to remove one of the users.

So, the closes that I got is this:

```
elif name.lower() == 'remove':
        rem = input("Insert user name to remove \n ...")
        with open('names.txt', 'r+') as f:
            f.delete(f.find(rem))
```

The text document is something like this:

```
Alex
Sarah
Mathew
Sophie
```

Only one string (user) every line.

Full code for better understanding:

```
snames = list()
f_n = (open('names.txt')).read()
print("Welcome to NAME.app")
#try:
while True:
    name = input("\n - Insert name to logg in \n - ADD to save new user \n - LIST to see saved users \n - REMOVE to delete a user \n ...")
    if name.lower() == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(n_input + '\n')
            f.close()
        continue

    elif name.lower() == "list":
        with open('names.txt') as f:
            print(f.read().splitlines())

    elif name in f_n:
        print("Logged as", name.upper())
        nxt = input('Welcome, press enter to continue \n')
        if nxt == '':
            break

    elif name.lower() == 'remove':
        rem = input("Insert user name to remove \n ...")
        with open('names.txt', 'r+') as f:
            f.delete(f.find(rem))

    elif name.lower() == "exit":
        exit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete specific strings from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356043/how-to-delete-specific-strings-from-a-file)

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both.

Comment: @tripleee Ok, sorry didn't know. Next time should I just python-3.x?

Comment: Probably yes, though these days Python 3 would be inferred if you don't say which version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elif name.lower() == 'remove':
        rem = input("Insert user name to remove \n ...")
        with open('names.txt', 'r+') as f:
            l=f.readlines()
            l=[z for z in l if rem not in z]
        with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(l)
```

However, this solution will remove ALL occurencies of this name in the file. If there are duplicates and you want to remove some of them, not all, code must be adjusted

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aletr\Desktop\Python projects\Restaurant software\r_0.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.write(l)
  File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 1487, in write
    s.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: can't write list to text stream

Comment: I have updated the code, please try again

Comment: Jesus, I love you. Thank you very much!!!