# How can I remove a string from a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I am trying to create a contact info txt file with python

```
what_you_want = input("Do you want to add or remove (if add write add), (if remove write remove): ")

if what_you_want == "remove":
    what_you_want_remove = input("What contact number you want to remove: ")
    with open("All Contact.txt", "r") as f:
        contact_info = f.readlines()
    if what_you_want_remove in contact_info:
        with open("All Contact.txt", "a") as f:
            if what_you_want_remove in contact_info:
                new_contact_info = contact_info.replace(what_you_want_remove, "")
            f.write(new_contact_info)
```

I couldn't find a way to directly remove something from a txt file so I want to put it into a list and then write it back to txt file but when I try to use remove command it doesn't work.

I want to ask if there is a way to remove something from a text file directly.

Comment: `new_contact_info = [contact for contact in contact_info if  contact != what_you_want_remove]` and then `f.write("\n".join(new_contact_info))`. I assume you have phone numbers in your file in each line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete specific strings from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356043/how-to-delete-specific-strings-from-a-file)

Comment: also converting string to upper or lower case while matching is preferred generally. so something like `if what_you_want.lower() == "remove": ` would be much better, because you would let users input uncased commands.

Comment: use `"w"` rather than `"a"` to write to file. `"a"` will append new contacts to older contacts, and so you'll have duplicate contacts.

Comment: `f.readlines()` will include `"\n"` at the end of returned list. use `f.read().splitlines()` instead, if `what_you_want_remove` is whole of line that you want to remove. then you can use `contact_info.remove(what_you_want_remove)` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a string or list, remove the substring, and write back to the file. For instance,

```py
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    string = string.replace(substring, "")
    f.write(string)
```

If `substring` does not exist in `file.txt`, the `replace` function will not perform any action. If you want the replacement to be case-insensitive, you could try lowering the entire buffer as well as the subtring via `string = string.lower()` and `substring = substring.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `del` to delete that entry.
Then overwrite the original file, making it one line shorter.

```
if what_you_want_remove in contact_info:
    i = contact_info.index(what_you_want_remove)
    del contact_info[i]

    with open("All Contact.txt", "w") as fout:
        fout.write("\n".join(contact_info)
        fout.write("\n")
```